# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in laravel when use Eloquent: Relationships

Tags: laravel, foreach, eloquent

I wanna get the class name of a user via the user ID. When I input the ID of a user so I will wanna get the class name. I have three tables such as `users` table, `classes` table, and `class_users` table. The `class_users` table is born from two `users` table and `classes` table.

- A `users` table has an `id, name, email, password`.
- A `classes` table has an `id, class_code, class_name`.
- A `class_users` table has an `id, class_id, user_id`

And this problem relates to Eloquent Relationships.

Thank you for help.

My Route:

```
Route::get('/find_classes/{id}','StudentController@find_classes');
```

My Controller function:

```
public function find_classes($id)
    {
        $users = User::find($id);

        foreach($users->classes as $class)
        {
            echo $class->name . '<br';
            dd($class);
        }
    }
```

My User Model:

```
public function classes()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Classes','class_users','user_id','class_id');
    }
```

Comment: Try `$users = User::with('clases')->find($id);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you might have the wrong relationship set up on your **User** model.  You have a one to many set up, but your DB is setup to handle a many to many.  I suggest you change your **User** model relationship:

```
public function classes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Classes');
}
```

Note, you may need to name the FK on that relation, as I see you have class_id on the table, but your actual class is named 'Classes'.  Check through your relationships to ensure this is explicit on the FK where it doesn't follow Laravel convention exactly.

With this relationship, your foreach loop should work.  It would be a good idea for efficiency, as mare96 noted, to eager load the classes on the $users collection when you query:

```
$users = User::with('classes')->find($id);
```